# Error ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected when running query

Tags: oracle-apex

01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

```
select project_name, my_date, sum(records_number) as 
from (
select project_name, 
  case 
    when :P33_RG = 'Daily' then
      to_char(date_sys, 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
    when :P33_RG = 'Weekly' then
      to_char(TRUNC(date_sys, 'IW'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  end as my_date,  
  BATCH.RECORDS_NUMBER
from BATCH
where date_sys between :P33_START_DATE and :P33_END_DATE
) my_records
group by project_name, my_date
;
```

any advice to fix the error would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: What are the data types and values of your bind variables?

Comment: :P33_START_DATE and :P33_END_DATE are dates (MM/DD/YYYY) from a date picker. :P33_RG is varchar values.

Answer (score 2):

`:P33_START_DATE` and `:P33_END_DATE` are not dates. They're strings with a date in the format of your apex application settings (MM/DD/YYYY). All page items in apex are strings when used as bind variables. What you defined them to be in apex (number, date, text field) only impacts how they're displayed on the screen, it doesn't set a datatype for the bind variables.

Try changing the query to

```
where date_sys between TO_DATE(:P33_START_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') and TO_DATE(:P33_END_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```